# How to align Button on the right of the image on desktop but below the image on mobile

Tags: buttons

I am using WordPress buttons I would like to know how to align Button on the right of the image on desktop but below the image on mobile.

Here is an example: https://www.verywellfit.com/best-ankle-weights-4158657

Please see the amazon buttons on this page.

On desktop this buttons align to the right. like this: 
[image]

and on mobile the buttons are below the image: 
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CSS would check the width of the screen, and (if small enough), change the display of the picture to block.  As taught by [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) ...

```
<style>
.the-image,
.the-price {
    display: inline-block;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .the-image {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>
<img class="the-image" src="...">
<div class="the-price">...</div>
```